# keep the same distance for circular TikZ nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to distribute several TikZ nodes around a centered node.

This is what I've tried so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (context) [draw,rectangle] {root};
            \foreach \ang/\t in {0/foo,90/bar,180/baz,270/foobar}{%
                \node [draw,rectangle,shift=(\ang:1.5cm)] {node \t};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is how the result looks like

[image]

As you can see the distance from nodes *foo* and *baz* to *root* is smaller than from *bar* and *foobar*.

Is there any way to correct the code, so the distance for each node is the same, no matter what angle I provide?

Comment: Here `1.5cm` is the distance between the center of  `root` node and each  centers of  surrounding nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same distance for square nodes is not obvious. In your example the centers are at the same distance. Here is one possible interpretation of "same distance" by changing the anchor of the surrounding nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lightgray] circle(1.5cm);
    \node (context) [draw,rectangle] {root};
    \foreach \ang/\t in {0/foo,90/bar,180/baz,270/foobar}{%
        \node [draw,rectangle,anchor={180+\ang}] at (\ang:1.5cm) {node \t};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]